# how to use $set, $inc etc. in c++ mongodb driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I was wondering how to use $set $inc in c+ mongodb driver. I can only call `update` to update the whole json string into the db like this: `_db_conn.update(db_name_str, mongo::Query(key_word), mongo::fromjson(json_str), true);`
**Are there any way to update partially, using $set, $inc option?**

when I check it on the internet, I found a similar solution in java, but I can't find it in c++ version documents...
`WriteResult result = mongoNsTemplate.getCollection("userStore").update(query.getQueryObject(), new BasicDBObject("$set", dbObject), true, false);`

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $set, $inc or other operations. The  document (`json_str` above) must be a document with update operator modifiers like $set or $inc instead of a full document. So if `json_str` contains something like:

```
string json_str = "{'$set': {'field1': 1}, '$inc': {'field2': 1}}";
```

Calling `_db_conn.update(db_name_str, mongo::Query(key_word), mongo::fromjson(json_str), true);` will:

- update the first matching document (or insert a new one if not found (upsert is true)
- set field1 to 1 (it will be added if it is not found)
- increment field2 by 1 (or set to 1 if not found, or cause an error if found but not a numerical value)

This is equivalent to using the mongo shell.